# Merging two tables using Eloquent (Without using DB::Table)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two models, Event and CoverEvent. A cover event can only be linked to one event.
I was able to do it using SQL. But I'd like to have it in a clean manner, using Eloquent.
How should I do this?

Many thanks!

Here's the SQL:

```
SELECT
    `cover_events`.`id`,
    `events`.`slug`,
    `events`.`title`,
    `events`.`subtitle`,
    `events`.`image`,
    `cover_events`.`columns`,
    `cover_events`.`right_align`,
    `cover_events`.`dark_text`,
    `cover_events`.`large`
FROM
    `cover_events`,
    `events`
WHERE
    `is_visible` LIKE 'true' AND
    `cover_events`.`event_id` = `events`.`id`
```

Which should result as the following array:

```
[
    [
        "id" => 1,
        "slug" => 'celine-dion-2020',
        "title" => 'Celine Dion',
        "subtitle" => '31 July 2020',
        "image" => env('APP_URL') . '/img/celine_dion.jpg',
        "columns" => 8,
        "right_align" => false,
        "dark_text" => true,
        "large" => true
    ],
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In eloquent you can only use relationships to join tables..

In `CoverEvent` class use a relationship

```
public function events()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Event', 'id', 'event_id');
}
```

Retrieve the result using

```
$res = CoverEvent::where('is_visible','true')->get();

foreach($res as $cover_event)
{
  $cover_event->events->slug;  // data from event class
  $cover_event->columns;    // data from cover_event class
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried out your code, but it's creating an array within array. I'd like to have the events array part of the main array, as one, not an array within an array. How could I do this? Thanks again, I appreciate it!

Comment: You can't join tables in eloquent without using relationship.If you want the result in one single array you have to use query builder.

Answer (score 1):

for example if your parent model is ManageClass and child modal is DaysClassDetails :-

```
class ManageClass extends Authenticatable
{   
   public function classType()
   {
      return $this->hasMany('App\DaysClassDetails','day_id','id');
   }
}
```

and enter this command in your controller function

```
ManageClass::with('classType')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Laravel's collection [merge()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-merge) method:

```
$events = Event::all()->merge(CoverEvent::all());
```